# Difference between definitions of consistent estimators

Tags: mathematical-statistics

My book on statistics defines an estimator $\hat{\theta}$ as consistent if, for a big sample:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{B}[\hat{\theta}] = 0 $$
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[\hat{\theta}] = 0 $$

Where $\mathbb{B}$ is the bias of the estimator and $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}$ is it's variance.

But econometrics books and more advanced books on statistics define consistency as this limit in probability:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|\hat{\theta}-\theta|>\epsilon) = 0$$
For all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.

I can see that the limit is the most general one, but I haven't found anywhere how that implies the conditions regarding variance and bias, can anyone point me where can I find it? (or if it's too basic/trivial, give me an idea of how I could do it?)

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

This connection is pretty straight-forward once you use [Chebyshev-Markov Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality). Putting it simply, it says that:

$\mathbf{P}[g(x) < r] \leq \frac{\mathbf{E}[g(x)]}{r}$

I think you can use it basically on the same way to show the implication on "left to right" direction:

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{P}[|\hat{\theta}-\theta|>\epsilon] = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{P}[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2>\epsilon^2] \leq \frac{\mathbf{E}[(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2]}{\epsilon^2}$

So if

1. $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{E}[\hat{\theta}] = \theta$
2. $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{V}[\hat{\theta}] = 0$

are both true, than

$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbf{P}[|\hat{\theta}-\theta|>\epsilon] \leq 0$

what implicates the limit on probability must be zero. I don't see a direct way to show it the other way, maybe their relation is not "if and only if" equivalency.

Comment: You are right that the other direction does not hold. Let $\theta_n (\omega)= n\mathbb{1}\{\omega \in \left(0,1/n\right]\}$ and note that this random variable converges point wise to 0 (and so in probability as well) but clearly $E[|\theta_n|^2]=n $ which diverges. Generally, this is an instance of the fact that convergence in measure (or almost sure convergence) does not imply $L^p$ convergence. The two forms of convergence are equivalent for uniformly integrable random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Bias and variance of an estimator $\hat \theta_n$ for $\theta$ both vanish as the sample size $n$ tends to infinity if and only if $\hat \theta_n$ converges in mean square (i.e., in $L^2$) to $\theta$  as $n \to \infty$. The [bias-variance decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Proof_of_variance_and_bias_relationship) of $\mathbb E_\theta[(\hat \theta_n - \theta)^2]$ immediately  shows why this is true.
Mean-square convergence implies convergence in probability, i.e. [(weak) consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Definition) of $\hat \theta_n$, but the converse is not true.

Hence, the definition in your book (sometimes referred to as mean-square consistency) is a stronger requirement than (weak) consistency.

Answer (score 0):

A real-world example of weak (and strong) convergence without mean-square convergence is the maximum likelihood estimator of the odds ratio in a $2\times 2$ table.

The estimator is infinite if either the off-diagonal cells is zero, which has non-zero probability (though exponentially small probability as the sample size increases).  This means that $\hat\theta$ doesn't have a finite mean or variance and so can't converge in mean square.  It still converges almost surely, since the sample cell proportions are means and so converge almost surely to the population cell proportions.

Answer (score 0):

I will expound on my comment as an answer: in general for any sequence of square integrable (i.e. the variance is finite) random variables, convergence in square-mean (or $L^2$) always implies convergence in probability by Markov's inequality (see Giovanni's answer). On the other hand, the converse is not true! Even if your sequence of estimators is square-integrable and converges in probability, it may not converge in square mean. See my comment on Giovanni's answer for that counterexample. Finally, the two forms of convergence are actually equivalent for [uniformly integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) random variables by the [Vitali convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem). This is a generalization of the dominated convergence theorem from measure theory. The proofs are standard and can be found in any book on measure theory or probability (see 13.7 in Williams' undergraduate book on probability, for instance).